# How to retrieve a list of all classes in a module in Haxe? (aka: helper classes)

Tags: list, macros, module, package, haxe

Considering a Haxe file defines a series of classes like so:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import haxe.unit.TestCase;

class MainTest extends Sprite { 
    public var testcase:Array<Class<TestCase>> = ???;
}

class TestSprite extends TestCase {
    function testBasic() {
        var sprite = new Sprite();
        sprite.x = 0;
        assertEquals(sprite.x, 0);
    }
}

class TestMovieClip extends TestCase {
    function testMovieClip() {
        var mc = new MovieClip();
        mc.nextFrame();
        assertEquals(mc.currentFrame, 2);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to obtain a list of all the helper classes (ex: `TestSprite` and `TestMovieClip`)? Preferably at runtime, but a macro that would return an `Array<Class<TestCase>>` would work fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a small macro helper library called [compiletime](https://github.com/jasononeil/compiletime) that can get all classes in a package, or all classes that extend a certain class.

```
haxelib install compiletime
```

And then get classes either by base class or by package:

```
var testcases = CompileTime.getAllClasses("my.package");
var testcases = CompileTime.getAllClasses(TestCase);
var testcases = CompileTime.getAllClasses("my.package",TestCase); // Both!
```

Now, that is getting them by package, not by module. Getting it by module might work, I'm not sure off the top of my head. But if you were to edit this part of the code:

https://github.com/jasononeil/compiletime/blob/master/src/CompileTime.hx#L208

And change it to also support getting by module, and send me a pull request, I would most certainly merge it :)

Good luck!

Comment: Cool this looks like it'll do the trick. I always thought though "module" and "package" were the same thing essentially? Here's another question: Will `CompileTime.getAllClasses(...)` find classes in subpackages as well (recursively)?

Comment: A "module" is a single ".hx" file.  A package is all of the .hx files in a given folder.  You can have as many classes or types as you want defined in each module, and as many modules as you want in each package.  About recursive packages, by default, `CompileTime.getAllClasses()` will get classes in sub-packages as well.  You can change this by doing `CompileTime.getAllClasses("my.package", false);` or similar.

Comment: Good to know. Sounds like keeping all my test cases in a "tests" package is ideal if I want them all collected in one call. Thanks for creating and sharing that class, I've used it before also for file reading (xml/json)

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful :)